# Pandas Dataframe column value's type is returning as a string though it is list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` and a column `A` i.e

```
A
['aa','bb','cc','dd']
['ee','ff','gg','hh']
.
.
.
```

when I find the `type` of `df['A'][0]`, I get `type(df['A'][0])` as `<class 'str'> (str)`, but it should return `list` as type.

Comment: How did you create your dataframe?

Comment: Simply by reading csv file

Comment: The above solution treats each character and square brackets as a element of a list .Hence this doesn't solve my problem.